# Format DateTime without converting to String in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a view in SQL Server 2012 and there is a column of containing dates&times. I have been trying to convert the date column as '20/10/2018 18:00' format (no second) by using this feature and lots of approaches on Stackoverflow and other web sites:

```
 FORMAT(StartDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm')
```

However, as the data type of this column is `Varchar` (String) rather than `DateTime`, I encountered some problems in C# side and I want to perform this conversion on the database side without changing the data type of the generated format). Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that you are storing dates as strings. This is a bad approach. Also keep in mind that when you use FORMAT the output is string data. If you want to format your data in the client a certain way you should have the database send the data as a datetime and do the formatting in the front end.

Comment: Your trying dd.{minutes}.yyyy   try FORMAT(StartDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')   HH for 24 hour clock

Comment: `Date` and `time` datatypes have no format. If you want a formatted date, then you need a `varchar`. What you should be doing is passing the value as a `datetime` to your application and then formatting the data in your presentation layer. Then your application can treat the data as what it is, a `datetime` and display it in a format that is right for your business.

Comment: @SeanLange I just want to display data and there is no problem formatting data during list instead of editing data.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Does it make any sense? Will it be still nvarchar (string) instead of DateTime?

Comment: To use FORMAT you would first have to convert your string into a datetime, then format it. But really, the issue is the datatype. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: A string is a string, and a date is a date.   There is no "date format"

Comment: Neither SQL Server *nor* C# associate a display format with a `DATETIME`/`DateTime`. It's all just a number under the covers, and how those numbers are displayed relies on the client(s) -- Management Studio, `Console.WriteLine`, and whatever you're having trouble with now. Look at what's processing the date/time values, and how you configure that to show things differently.

Comment: Dates in that sort of format tend to get converted on clients depending on regional settings - if you are transferring it as a string, you might want to look at converting to iso8601 format, but you'd need to reliable make your date string into a date first.  example SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(33), GETDATE(), 126)

Comment: Thanks a lot all of your helps, I am appreciated your valuable comments... On the other hand, could you please clarify me about the following issues in order to fix the problem via a best solution for this scenario??? >>>

Comment: I think one of the best way for me seem to be format DateTime as string in ViewModel or AutoMapper's config, but the second option does not work. For the ViewModel side, I think to use string for the DateTime field but I am not sure if it will be a problem as the property in the model.ts file is Date type. So, what about creating an extra parameter in the ViewModel and convert & format my DateTime value as string??? Is it the best suitable scenario for me???

Comment: @Cato Have you look at my last comment?

Comment: Not really sure what you need help with. Not even sure what you are trying to do. The only thing I know for sure is you should not store dates as varchar.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't have a "date format" per se. The formatting of datetime fields is only performed when presenting the datetime to an output - that is, when converting it to a string.

There is a default format for presentation that is controlled by the server's collation setting. However, internally the date is stored as a numeric value (actual format varies by type, as `datetime` and `datetime2` have different internal formats), and that value has no associated formatting.

You can store your date without seconds by using a `smalldatetime` field, or by manipulating the input data to trim off the seconds value. But, unless you store your date as a string, which is **absolutely not recommended**, you will not be able to save an output format different from the default collation-driven format in a datetime field.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of the contributors and answers. In this case, I have to perform format operations on program side rathe than database side. Regards...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually one of the best way for me seem to be format DateTime as string in ViewModel or AutoMapper's config, but the second option does not work. For the ViewModel side, I think to use string for the DateTime field but I am not sure if it will be a problem as the property in the model.ts file is Date type. So, what about creating an extra parameter in the ViewModel and convert & format my DateTime value as string??? Is it the best suitable scenario for me???

Answer (score 0):

I would migrate that column to a `datetime` (or some variant) if possible. Alternatively if that would affect too many things, you could make a computed column on the table which converts the string date you have to a `datetime`. That way the database doesn't have to care about the formatting at all; it just works with the proper `DateTime` data type.

If neither of those is an option, you can just pas the string to C# and use `DateTime.TryParse()` to convert it to a C# `DateTime` object.

In either case, it's preferable to work with the date as a `DateTime` up until the very last minute where you need to format it for display somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually one of the best way for me seem to be format DateTime as string in ViewModel or AutoMapper's config, but the second option does not work. For the ViewModel side, I think to use string for the DateTime field but I am not sure if it will be a problem as the property in the model.ts file is Date type. So, what about creating an extra parameter in the ViewModel and convert & format my DateTime value as string??? Is it the best suitable scenario for me???